# Getting a "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error' what(): invalid UTF-8 byte at index 0: 0x81"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I'm working on a coding problem on a website and when I compile my code it gives me:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'   what():
> [json.exception.type_error.316] invalid UTF-8 byte at index 0: 0x81
> Aborted exit status 134

However, when I compile on Sublime it works just fine with the correct output. Is there something wrong with how I'm using the ASCII values to store into the string variable `answer`? Here is my code:

```
string caesarCypherEncryptor(string str, int key) {
    string answer = "";
    for(char letter : str) {
        // if it goes over 'z': get amount pass 'z' and start at 'a'
        if(letter + key > int('z')) {
            // push back char into answer string
            answer += ((letter + key) % int('z') + int('a'));  
            continue;
        }
        // else just add key from current position
        answer += letter + key; 
    }
    return answer;
}

int main() {

    cout << caesarCypherEncryptor("mvklahvjcnbwqvtutmfafkwiuagjkzmzwgf", 7) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *However, when I compile on Sublime it works just fine* -- I don't see any program.  I see a function.  Where is the `main` function, sample data, and call to this function?  This is not a [mcve]

Comment: Also, `Sublime` is not a C++ compiler.  It is a code editor and an IDE.

Comment: It is compiler-dependent if `char` is signed or unsigned. Arithmetic overflow of signed integer types leads to *undefined behavior*. If `char` is signed then e.g. `'z' + 7` will overflow. If you explicitly specify unsigned (as in `unsigned char letter`) what is the behavior?

Comment: I got the same result with the unsigned char letter

Comment: Well please read the error message again. What does it say? From where is it reported? What do you think happen when you have a character which is not a valid UTF-8 character, and then try to pass it on as a UTF-8 character? And remember that the ASCII alphabet is a ***seven*** bit encoding system, and UTF-8 is using ASCII for the first 127 characters. Character values above `0x80` are not valid as single characters.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried out this question, probably on the same website as you mentioned.
To any one in the future who is faced with this issue, the problem is in the line
of comparison:

```
if(letter + key > int('z'))
```

In the above line the ascii value will cross a certain limit which JSON excepts as valid characters, if key is greater than 26, and which by the way is also part of useless calculation, because a key > 26, for example say 27 is same as key = 1.

Hence,  the first line of the solution should be key = (key % 26).

This prevents the above given JSON Exception error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too.
This basically happens when we add int to character and final ascii value cross 127. As result, the ascii value rolls over. i.e. `'z' + 7 = 129` - but it rolls over and becomes - `129 - 127 = 2`.

Basically you need to use below condition:

```
if((unsigned int)(letter + key) > 'z')
```

Please try this out and let me know if this helps.